Where in node.js source code does the process of JIT compiling the javascript executable begin
There is a border between launching the node.js platform itself and executing .js files.
I am curious to know where is that moment in the node.js source code that starts executing the compiled code?

I found the next:
MaybeLocal<Value> BuiltinLoader::CompileAndCall(Local<Context> context,
                                                const char* id,
                                                int argc,
                                                Local<Value> argv[],
                                                Realm* optional_realm) {
  // Arguments must match the parameters specified in
  // BuiltinLoader::LookupAndCompile().
  MaybeLocal<Function> maybe_fn = LookupAndCompile(context, id, optional_realm);
  Local<Function> fn;
  if (!maybe_fn.ToLocal(&fn)) {
    return MaybeLocal<Value>();
  }
  Local<Value> undefined = Undefined(context->GetIsolate());
  return fn->Call(context, undefined, argc, argv);
}

Do I understand correctly that fn->Call(context, undefined, argc, argv) runs the compiled script code?

You can use source.chromium.org to find out what v8::Function::Call does.

A JIT system does not compile code to optimized machine code all at once; that's the point of the term "JIT". From function call to function call, whether the target has been compiled to machine code or is in some intermediate form you can't know until you get there.

@jmrk I searched as you said, got to the Invoke operation and the line in it "// Entering JavaScript." - but I don't see any operations that would run the script. What am I missing?

@MaximPro stub_entry.Call further down in the same function is the crucial bit.

@jmrk If you look for the definition of Call from stub_entry it directs it here. And it’s not clear what this is? Can you clarify where stub_entry.Call refers to and what happens there? And if that link is correct, then what is fn_ptr_ and what does it contain? Sorry for a lot of questions :(

@MaximPro GeneratedCode::Call, as the name implies, is what calls into generated code. fn_ptr_ is a pointer to this code that's being called.

@jmrk I found out that the code can be called with or without a simulator. If the execution occurs with the simulator, it eventually leads here and here it is clear that the instructions in the loop are executed.
And what happens without the simulator? The write return fn(args...); or return fn_ptr_(args...); can occur. If with the simulator, it is still clear that the instructions are executed. But what without the simulator?

Without simulator, the CPU executes the generated machine code. fn_ptr_(args...) is exactly what that transfer of control looks like in C++ code.

@jmrk interesting, but still unclear about other cases, when they are used. I created another question related to this topic, could you please give a detailed answer?
